# Create an ojbect of data inside FB.api function

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery-callback

I am trying to fetch the user's album from facebook, I have done with this now I need to create an object inside the FB.api function with albumID and albumCover.

Because FB.api is an asynchronous function that is why I am unable to do that.

Here is my code:

```
var getUserAlbum = function () {
    var token = 'access token';
    var albums = [];
    FB.api(
        "/me/albums/", {'accessToken': token},
        function (album) {
            if (album && !album.error) {
                $(album.data).each(function (k, v) {
                    FB.api(
                        "/"+ v.id +"/picture",
                        function (albumCover) {
                            if (albumCover && !albumCover.error) {
                                var id = v.id;
                                var url = k.url;
                                $(albumCover.data).each(function (i, k) {
                                    albums.push({
                                        "id": v.id,
                                        "url": k.url 
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
                console.log(albums); // it is giving me blank array
                           //because it executes before FB.api ends
            }
        }
    );
   console.log(albums); // also blank here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed after you get the response in the callback, simple! It's the most obvious way to handle the async (like ajax) requests.

Code:

```
var getUserAlbum = function () {
  ...
  ...
  FB.api(
      "/"+ v.id +"/picture",
      function (albumCover) {
          if (albumCover && !albumCover.error) {
              var id = v.id;
              var url = k.url;
              $(albumCover.data).each(function (i, k) {
                  albums.push({
                      "id": v.id,
                      "url": k.url 
                  });
              });
              // EDIT
              console.log(albums);
              proceed(albums);
          }
      }
  );
  ...
  ...
}

function proceed(albums) {
  // do whatever you want to do with the `albums` 
}
```